Kubernetes configuration with Duende Identity Server and Next js web app
I have a school project where I had to develop an auction application using microservices, containerize it with Docker, and then deploy it locally first with Kubernetes and finally on Azure. My problem occurs when clicking the 'Login' button on my web app, which fails to redirect to my authentication microservice. The authentication microservice is developed in C# using Duende Identity Server, and my web app is developed in NextJS. My Docker configuration works perfectly, but I can't configure everything for Kubernetes. All my microservices work with Kubernetes except for this redirection issue from my web app to my authentication service. It might be due to my nginx or ingress configuration.
Here is the error:
2024-06-19 21:46:12 [next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
2024-06-19 21:46:12 https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 {
2024-06-19 21:46:12   error: {
2024-06-19 21:46:12     message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443',
2024-06-19 21:46:12     stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443\n' +
2024-06-19 21:46:12       '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)\n' +
2024-06-19 21:46:12       '    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17)',
2024-06-19 21:46:12     name: 'Error'
2024-06-19 21:46:12   },
2024-06-19 21:46:12   providerId: 'id-server',
2024-06-19 21:46:12   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443'
2024-06-19 21:46:12 }

I can't put my docker-compose and Kubernetes files so here's my GitHub link Kubernetes branch and kubernetes folder: https://github.com/Nelahio/cube/tree/kubernetes/kubernetes
Please see authentification-deployment, webapp-deployment, nginx-proxy and ingress-service files and docker-compose.
Maybe it's an ssl error, ingress or nginx?
I've tried changing my AUTH_URL variable in the web app configuration multiple times with all possible values, but without success. Similarly, I've tried several nginx and ingress configurations, but nothing works. I must have missed something, but I don't know what.
I've tried to ping auth.cube.com in my webapp pod and it works.
Thank you very much in advance.
Edit:
Minimal Kubernetes manifests:
Webapp variables:
spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: nelahio/web-app:latest
          env:
            - name: NEXTAUTH_SECRET
              value: something
            - name: NEXTAUTH_URL
              value: https://app.cube.com
            - name: API_URL
              value: http://gateway-clusterip/
            - name: AUTH_URL
              value: https://auth.cube.com
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

authentification manifest:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: authentification-service
          image: nelahio/authentification-service:latest
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
              value: Production
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: http://+:80
            - name: ClientApp
              value: https://app.cube.com
            - name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection
              value: Server=postgres-clusterip:5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgrespw;Database=identity
            - name: VIRTUAL_HOST
              value: auth.cube.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: authentification-clusterip
spec:
  selector:
    app: authentification-service
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

nginx manifest:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-proxy
          image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/docker.sock
              name: docker-sock
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/certs
              name: nginx-certs
      volumes:
        - name: docker-sock
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: nginx-certs
          hostPath:
            path: ./devcerts
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      nodePort: 30443

Ingress manifest:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  labels:
    name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - app.cube.com
        - api.cube.com
      secretName: cube-app-tls
    - hosts:
        - auth.cube.com
      secretName: cube-com-tls
  rules:
    - host: app.cube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapp-clusterip
                port:
                  number: 3000
    - host: api.cube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: gateway-clusterip
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: auth.cube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: authentification-clusterip
                port:
                  number: 80

Also, I've modified my hosts file to add this line:
127.0.0.1 auth.cube.com app.cube.com api.cube.com

And I use SSL certs mkcert. Maybe these informations can help.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  This may involve trimming down your YAML manifests and other source to the minimum necessary.  The 127.0.0.1 in the error message is suspicious; if that error comes from the browser, it refers to the system running the browser, and (probably) not your Kubernetes Ingress or any of the involved pods.

I've edited, hope it's better
